# Eclipse: Android Runtime Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, runtime

I used libgdx to setup my project, eclipse luna as an editor, and avd for emulation.

(I know I have the latest Android Studio)

When I run my app, after the compile I have this...         (LogCat)

```
(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Libgdx requires OpenGL ES 2.0
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.createGLSurfaceView(AndroidGraphics.java:127)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(AndroidGraphics.java:107)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(AndroidGraphics.java:100)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.init(AndroidApplication.java:133)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.initialize(AndroidApplication.java:99)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.my.app.android.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(AndroidLauncher.java:14)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  ... 11 more
```

Here is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.app.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.app.android.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my AndroidLauncher.java

```
package com.my.app.android;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.my.app.MyApp;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new MyApp(), config);
    }
}
```

Comment: well if you do not want to share the code that is causing this problem we can not really help you

Comment: whoops... thx for reminding me

Comment: User has already shared details/code, so let's prevent it from closing the question!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a root cause buried in your stacktrace:

```
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Libgdx requires OpenGL ES 2.0 04-16 01:43:02.160: E/AndroidRuntime(620):
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.createGLSurfaceView(AndroidGraphics.java:127)
```

You should ensure the device/simulator you're using for testing supports OpenGL ES 2.0.